# Working with ADODB recordset

Tags: datatable, asp.net-4.0, adodb

I am using VS 2010. The requirement to pull the `ADODB recordset` and convert them into `DataTable`. Is there any extension method or library available in ASP.NET to convert `ADODB recordset` to Datatable.

I can understand using `OleDataAdapter` we can achieve it. But I am curious to know is there any utility available in ASP.net so that I can make use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the simple approaches which helps you to convert `ADODB Recordset` to `DataTable`.

```
 public static DataTable ADODBRSetToDataTable(this ADODB.Recordset adodbRecordSet)
  {
                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt,adodbRecordSet);
                return dt;
  }
```

Ensure you have made a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 library or >

Note : I haven't tested the code.